# Resize multi-dimensional arrays to add empty columns and rows

Tags: javascript

How can I add empty columns and rows to a multi-dimensional array?

Example array:

```
// (1s are just a placeholder for any data)
let arr = [ 
     [1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1],
    ];
```

After adding 3 empty columns and 2 rows:

```
let result = [ 
      [1,1,1,1,"","",""],
      [1,1,1,1,"","",""],
      [1,1,1,1,"","",""],
      ["","","","","","",""],
      ["","","","","","",""],
     ];
```

Comment: How about `arr[arr.length + newRows] = []` ? Use the same technique you're using to extend the row arrays, in other words.

Comment: If I do that I get:  ` [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, , , '' ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, , , , , , '' ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, , , , , , , , , '' ],
  ,
  ,
  [],
  ,
  ,
  [],
  ,
  ,
  [] ]`.

Comment: Or, I do not get how to apply what you mean

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting. If you want to add rows, you have to add new arrays to the outer array. You should probably do that *before* you add columns to the inner arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
];

let newCols = 3, newRows = 2

arr.forEach(i=>i.push(...Array(newCols).fill('')))
for(let i=0; i<newRows; i++) arr.push(Array(arr[0].length).fill(''))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This adds newRows arrays of intended size (innerSize) to the array first, then «fills» all arrays to the intended size.

```js
let arr= [ 
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
];

const newCols = 3,
      newRows = 2,
      innerSize = arr[0].length + newCols,
      fillValue = "";

for(var i = 0; i < newRows; i++){
  arr.push(new Array(innerSize).fill(fillValue));
}
arr = arr.map(x => x.concat(new Array(innerSize - x.length).fill(fillValue)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

In a scenario, where the existing length of inner arrays is always the same, you can follow these steps:

1. Add rows with empty elements with the same number of existing columns. You can use the [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method for this.
2. Add the new columns to all the rows

It can look something like this:

```js
function resizeArr() {
  let arr = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
  ];

  let newCols = 3;
  let newRows = 2;

  // Add new rows
  for (let i = 0; i < newRows; i++) {
    arr.push(Array(arr[0].length).fill(""))
  }

  //Add new empty cols
  arr.forEach((row) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < newCols; i++) {
      row.push("")
    }
  });

  console.log(arr)
}

resizeArr()
```